# How can I add a caption to this image in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website, and I have these two images in mobile view. Their width is 30%. These two images are side by side, like this [image: pic of example]

I want to add a little caption below each image.

```
                    <div class = "unique-img1">
                    <a href ="https://www.tinkercad.com/things/5eLpG1ckaVV-big-man-hoverboard-jam-final-/editel?sharecode=2xiGuCn3iHM6gQ_TZ1J2N_CHOzqMCqCwx5fIz0WU2Sc"><img class = "tcimg1" src = "img/tinkercadimg.png" alt = "tinker cad link 1 normal"> </a> 
                    <!-- <p class = "caption1"> Three fan model</p> -->
                <div>
                <div class = "unique-img2">
                    <a href ="https://www.tinkercad.com/things/4zLV1NfIvHD-copy-of-sailboat-2-back-fan-1-base-fan/editel?sharecode=i4cV464Cnu0kmQByOnSVp5WCgOQJZHWV0wGtW6Oa00I"><img class = "tcimg2" src = "img/tinkercadimg.png" alt = "tinker cad link 2 + servo"> </a> 
                    <!-- <p class = "caption2"> Tinkercad Link to sailboat model </p> -->
                </div>
```

css:

```
   /* code for images in unique section  */
.unique-section img {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
}
/* tinkercad image right  */
img.tcimg2 {
    float: right;   
}

.unique-img1 {
    float: left;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just uncomment the p tag in your code . It will work as caption then.

```
 <div class = "unique-img1">
                        <a href ="https://www.tinkercad.com/things/5eLpG1ckaVV-big-man-hoverboard-jam-final-/editel?sharecode=2xiGuCn3iHM6gQ_TZ1J2N_CHOzqMCqCwx5fIz0WU2Sc"><img class = "tcimg1" src = "img/tinkercadimg.png" alt = "tinker cad link 1 normal"> </a> 
                   <br>     <p class = "caption1"> Three fan model</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "unique-img2">
                        <a href ="https://www.tinkercad.com/things/4zLV1NfIvHD-copy-of-sailboat-2-back-fan-1-base-fan/editel?sharecode=i4cV464Cnu0kmQByOnSVp5WCgOQJZHWV0wGtW6Oa00I"><img class = "tcimg2" src = "img/tinkercadimg.png" alt = "tinker cad link 2 + servo"> </a> 
                    <br>    <p class = "caption2"> Tinkercad Link to sailboat model </p> 
                    </div>
```

In case you want your caption to be a hyperlink like your image, just place the p tag after the img tag (both inside an a tag ).

```
    <div class = "unique-img1">
                                <a href ="https://www.tinkercad.com/things/5eLpG1ckaVV-big-man-hoverboard-jam-final-/editel?sharecode=2xiGuCn3iHM6gQ_TZ1J2N_CHOzqMCqCwx5fIz0WU2Sc">
    <img class = "tcimg1" src = "img/tinkercadimg.png" alt = "tinker cad link 1 normal">
 <br>   <p class = "caption1"> Three fan model</p>
     </a> 
     </div>
                            <div class = "unique-img2">
                                <a href ="https://www.tinkercad.com/things/4zLV1NfIvHD-copy-of-sailboat-2-back-fan-1-base-fan/editel?sharecode=i4cV464Cnu0kmQByOnSVp5WCgOQJZHWV0wGtW6Oa00I">
        <img class = "tcimg2" src = "img/tinkercadimg.png" alt = "tinker cad link 2 + servo"> 
      <br>  <p class = "caption2"> Tinkercad Link to sailboat model </p>
        </a> 
                                 
                            </div>
```

Comment: if i do that, the text won't be below the image, itll be beside it.

Comment: You can add a break tag in that case

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class = "unique-section">
  <div class = "unique-img1">
    <a href ="https://www.tinkercad.com/things/5eLpG1ckaVV-big-man-hoverboard-jam-final-/editel?sharecode=2xiGuCn3iHM6gQ_TZ1J2N_CHOzqMCqCwx5fIz0WU2Sc">
      <img class = "tcimg1" src = "img/tinkercadimg.png" alt = "tinker cad link 1 normal"> 
    </a> 
    <p class = "caption1"> Three fan model</p>
  <div>
                
  <div class = "unique-img2">
    <a href ="https://www.tinkercad.com/things/4zLV1NfIvHD-copy-of-sailboat-2-back-fan-1-base-fan/editel?sharecode=i4cV464Cnu0kmQByOnSVp5WCgOQJZHWV0wGtW6Oa00I">
      <img class = "tcimg2" src = "img/tinkercadimg.png" alt = "tinker cad link 2 + servo"> 
    </a> 
    <p class = "caption2"> Tinkercad Link to sailboat model </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.unique-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.unique-img1,
.unique-img2 {
  width: 30%;
}

.unique-section img{
  width: 100%:
}
```

Comment: for some reason, when  I do 

`.unique-section2{
 display:flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}`

, the images still stack ontop of eachother instead of lining up side by side.

I've found the only way to acc make the images side by side is using float.

Comment: also, no matter what I do, the text seems to up side by side of the image instead of being below the image. like [this](https://imgur.com/a/fnGLMn8) on phone and tablet view

Comment: Float is too much old. In the recent days, flex and grid is popular for alignment.

Comment: yeah I understand. But I can't seem to figure out how to make it work with flexbox. Each attempt has them ontop of eachother and not side by side. But it's okay. I found a solution (it's not optimal but its a solution)